# Using AJAX to call JavaScript remotely

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Let's say I have a js page (uploaded to some server, with this address: myaddress/service.js) with this code:

```
nsBob = {
 a: function(someParam) {...do something here and return result},
 b: function() {...do something here and return result},
 c: function() {...do something here and return result}
};
```

Now let's say I have an app somewhere, in a different domain, and I want to use one of nsBob's functions. nsBob.a(something) for example.

How can I make this simple ajax call for this one specific function in a different domain to get the result data for this function only?
With or without passing parameters.
I'd really appreciate it if you can show me a full working example somehow.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you know the link, you can circumvent the CrossDomain issues by writing a server script to fetch it and then render it to the page.
ex:  `<?php echo file_get_contents('website_address');?>` and then reference this server file in your code with the param of the address you want.

Comment: How can I do this without any php code but with just javascript calls?

Comment: The only way to... prevent others from seeing this code is through some use of authentication. Since auth tokens and what not can't be sent using a `<script>` tag, your only options are get it as text (while properly following CORS) and evaling it, or by not worrying about it in the first place. Obfuscation does nothing to prevent people from seeing how the code works or reusing it, and even using the CORS option the client who downloads it will be able to see it. The best option is to just not worry about it, and move sensitive stuff out of client-side code.

Answer (score -1):

There is [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for one. You could probably also get the script as a text and use [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to run it. Full owrking example I don't have time for right now, sorry.

Comment: eval is bad to tell people to use in this case.  Actually in just about all cases, eval is more or less just bad and in a sense depreciated by practical reasoning

Comment: They say it's nearly always bad. Oh well, I'm just presenting different options / possibilities.

Comment: Problem is - I don't want to expose my code. I want to use "service.js" as a service only. Get calls to functions and return data.

Comment: @FED I don't think there is any real way to hide your JavaScript like that. You could possibly come up with some PHP-hack on the other side, but that too will most likely expose the code at some point or the other. How about obfuscating the JavaScript?

Comment: Yep, that's what i'll probably do. Is obfuscating safe enough?

And then - how can I return the full nsBob object with it's functions via ajax call from the app using js? Just a script injector?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'safe enough'. If the script is only couple hundred lines long it's fast to deobfuscate by hand. Obfuscating isn't really meant for security, but for minimizing the code. Unreadability is a "plus". However obfuscating should keep at least the stupid people from using your script. Smart people will make their own anyway. I'd probably go with the getScript-approach unless you know the dangers of eval.

Comment: From my understanding of the question, OP wanted to get stuff from different servers.  The definition of $.getScript(url) says *Load a JavaScript file from **the** server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.*  It makes me think that XD script files might fail in this case?